# How to upgrade my Activities to Fragments  and avoid ClassCastException?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have quite a large hierarchy of classes that are Activities. I just installed the v4 compatibility package. What is the easiest way to get all my Activities in a way that I can use them in a Fragment with a TabHost inside of it?

Line of code:

```
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("feed").setIndicator("Feed"), FActivity.class, null);
```

Line 165:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
                return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
            }
```

Specifically I want to avoid errors like:

```
07-19 01:33:24.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17581): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.c.FActivity
07-19 01:33:24.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17581):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:378)
07-19 01:33:24.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17581):     at com.c.Main$TabsAdapter.getItem(Main.java:165)
07-19 01:33:24.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17581):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:62)
```

Comment: [Using Fragment of Android Compatibility Package](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-fragment-of-android-compatibility.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few links that you might find interesting. There is an example of creating a two-activity application, and then implementing fragments into it.

[Android User Interface Design: Working With Fragments](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

[Android Compatibility: Working with Fragments](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/)

Hope this helps.